# Using delete_if to delete single value of hash not the entire hash RUBY

Tags: ruby

I have a array

```
array_hash = [
  {
    "array_value" => 1,
    "other_values" => "whatever",
    "inner_value" => [
      {"iwantthis" => "forFirst"},
      {"iwantthis2" => "forFirst2"},
      {"iwantthis3" => "forFirst3"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "array_value" => 2,
    "other_values" => "whatever2",
    "inner_value" => [
      {"iwantthis" => "forSecond"},
      {"iwantthis2" => "forSecond2"},
      {"iwantthis3" => "forSecond3"}
    ]
  },
]
```

I want to delete inner value or pop it out (i prefer pop).
So my output should be this:

```
array_hash = [
  {
    "array_value" => 1,
    "other_values" => "whatever"
  },
  {
    "array_value" => 2,
    "other_values" => "whatever2"
  },
]
```

I tried `delete_if`

```
array_hash.delete_if{|a| a['inner_value'] }
```

But it deletes all data in the array. Is there any solution?

Comment: You need to iterate over all elements of the array and call `delete_if` on the individual hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found it,

```
array_hash_popped = array_hash.map{ |a| a.delete('inner_value') }
```

This will pop (because I want pop as stated in the question) the inner_value out and hence inner value will be reduced/deleted from array_hash.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "pop". Can you explain that?

Comment: It means removing a particular element from the variable and storing it to another variable, just like you pop out top element array values.

Comment: OK, I understand.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
array_hash.map{ |a| {'array_value' => a['array_value'], 'other_values' => a['other_values'] }}
```

Comment: Nice solution, I +1ed. But I prefer pop. Check my solution, it will pop as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are telling ruby to delete all hashes that have a key called *inner_value*. That explains why the array remains empty.

What you should probably do instead is:

```
array_hash.each { |x| x.delete 'inner_value' }
```

which means: for each hash in this array, erase the *inner_value* key.